# I am trying to create a diffrent list item for each string in an array

Tags: reactjs

I would like for this map method to create one list item for each string but it is bunching them all together.

This is what my output looks like

-Plan and execute content marketing efforts globally to attract, engage and retain high value customersExecute content expansion efforts including incremental content-focused emails, website placements, etc.Coordinate content distribution, digital and social marketing efforts for the Ideas Center and other content related-effortsLead internal writer for new product launch for BizBox powered by Office Depot. Partnered with PWC to produce Beta site

```
                       {
                        id: '2',
                        position: 'Marketing Lead, High Value Customers & Businesses, Global E-commerce',
                        tenure: ' 4/17 – 8/17',
                        duties:['Plan and execute content marketing efforts globally to attract, engage and retain high value customers','Execute content expansion efforts including incremental content-focused emails, website placements, etc.','Coordinate content distribution, digital and social marketing efforts for the Ideas Center and other content related-efforts','Lead internal writer for new product launch for BizBox powered by Office Depot. Partnered with PWC to produce Beta site']
                    },
                  {resume.map(resume => {
             return <ExperienceCompany id={resume.id} company={resume.company} location={resume.location} tenure={resume.tenure} duties={resume.duties}/>
              })}

                 {props.duties.map(resume => {
                  return <li id={props.id}>{props.duties}</li>
                  })}
```

Comment: What is your question? You should also clearly state what you expect and what you got instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell with the limited context, but you should change the naming in your map callback

```
{props.duties.map((duty, i) => {
  return <li key={i}>{duty}</li>
})}
```

## Currently

In your use of `props.duties.map(resume => ...`, `resume` is your abitrary variable name for each element in `duties`, and it's not being used in your `return`.